# Expat unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, linker-errors, unresolved-external, xmp

I've got troubles finding why i've got unresolved external symbol when linking a static library (XMP with expat included) in a shared lib (it's a firefox xpcom component).

I'm under windows using the Windows compiler (flag : "-Od -MDd") and mozilla-firefox 14.

The static library is the XMPCore library from Adobe XMP's SDK : there's no problems building it (expat's source code are included as part of a third-party library)

When building my xpcom module, i've got this at linking stage :

> *symbole externe non résolu means unresolved external symbol !*

```
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_SetCommentHandler référencé dans la fonction "public: __thiscall
ExpatAdapter::ExpatAdapter(bool)" (??0ExpatAdapter@@QAE@_N@Z)
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_SetProcessingInstructionHandler référencé dans la fonction "publi
c: __thiscall ExpatAdapter::ExpatAdapter(bool)" (??0ExpatAdapter@@QAE@_N@Z)
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_SetCdataSectionHandler référencé dans la fonction "public: __this
call ExpatAdapter::ExpatAdapter(bool)" (??0ExpatAdapter@@QAE@_N@Z)
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_SetCharacterDataHandler référencé dans la fonction "public: __thi
scall ExpatAdapter::ExpatAdapter(bool)" (??0ExpatAdapter@@QAE@_N@Z)
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_SetElementHandler référencé dans la fonction "public: __thiscall
ExpatAdapter::ExpatAdapter(bool)" (??0ExpatAdapter@@QAE@_N@Z)
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_SetNamespaceDeclHandler référencé dans la fonction "public: __thi
scall ExpatAdapter::ExpatAdapter(bool)" (??0ExpatAdapter@@QAE@_N@Z)
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_SetUserData référencé dans la fonction "public: __thiscall ExpatA
dapter::ExpatAdapter(bool)" (??0ExpatAdapter@@QAE@_N@Z)
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_ParserCreateNS référencé dans la fonction "public: __thiscall Exp
atAdapter::ExpatAdapter(bool)" (??0ExpatAdapter@@QAE@_N@Z)
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_ParserFree référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual __thiscall
 ExpatAdapter::~ExpatAdapter(void)" (??1ExpatAdapter@@UAE@XZ)
xmpcore.lib(ExpatAdapter.obj) : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu __imp__XML_Parse référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual void __thiscall
 ExpatAdapter::ParseBuffer(void const *,unsigned int,bool)" (?ParseBuffer@ExpatAdapter@@UAEXPBXI_N@Z)
xmp.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 10 externes non résolus
```

So i thought that those functions from expat was missing from my XMP's static build so i've checked using objdump -t to list the symbols i found this :

```
../third-party/expat/lib/xmlparse.obj:     file format pe-i386

SYMBOL TABLE:
...
[109](sec  5)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000ff0 _XML_SetCommentHandler
...

../XMPCore/source/ExpatAdapter.obj:     file format pe-i386

SYMBOL TABLE:
...
[251](sec  0)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __imp__XML_SetCommentHandler
...
```

The implementation of these functions is included so i need hints : Could someone help me with this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my error : the readme from Adobe XMP's SDK wasn't complete because they forgot to tell to define XML_STATIC in the compiling stage if you want to build a static library using expat (-DXML_STATIC). Hope it can help others with the same problems

Comment: Could you explain how to do this?  Thanks

Comment: With CMake, you could add this line: "add_compile_definitions(XML_STATIC)" on the 3rd or 4th line of CMakeLists.txt. I used this in order to successfully compile LibKML 1.3.0 for Windows. A real pain in the ass, but finally I was able to create some static libraries and use that library in my project. Many thanks to the author of this comment, a real life saver!

Comment: If you're compiling on Windows using LibXml2 with CMake, you need to add the `LIBXML_STATIC` definition with `add_compile_definitions(LIBXML_STATIC)`, otherwise you'll get a lot of __imp_xml* errors. (Tested with libxml2-2.9.10)